# Download & open file from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-5.0

My silverlight 5 application has a third party grid. I need to export the grid & open the excel for user machine. The grid supports export feature which writes the content in `Stream stream = dialog.OpenFile()` Export is working fine. The new requirement is to open the file instead just saving the file. I cannot run my app in OOB, I also hate to push the file to my service / website and download file from there. Is there any effective workaround or solution to open the content in user's excel application without making application as trusted with certificates?

Answer (score 0):

It is an essential security feature of Silverlight to **not allow** starting other applications or even open websites when running in browser and not running as trusted application.

So as you might have guessed (as there were no answers to this question for about one and a half years) the answer to your question is: No, there is no effective workaround for your problem.

I had that problem myself, and went for the solution to send the file to a webservice and store it on a network-share. From there the user is then able to open it...